# In Ingress, can I link to a portal with less than 8 resonators?

Tags: ingress

If I have a key to a portal with 8 resonators, and I approach a portal with only 7 resonators, I cannot link the portals - I have to add a resonator first.

But what about the opposite situation? If I have a key to a portal with only 7 resonators, and I approach a portal with 8 resonators, can I create a link between them?

(If not, there may be some point to destroying only one resonator of a strong enemy portal - to prevent links from being created.)

Comment: And destruction of a resonator also reduces the range of the portal, so you may break links - even with the destruction of only one resonator.

Comment: @Rory: Understood, but in my experience most portals don't have links that approach anywhere near the portals limit, so destroying one resonator isn't sufficient to break links. You must also consider that destroying one resonator gives the enemy an easy opportunity to replace it, which is worth more AP to them than you received for destroying it.  It may be counter-productive to your team.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't link two portals [unless they both have all 8 resonators](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808251?hl=en&ref_topic=2799270) :

> Both the Origin and Destination Portals of the Link must have all
>   eight Resonators deployed on each portal